# Remounting an USB-device

Tags: automount, usb-drive

When I connect an external HDD or an USB stick, it gets mounted automatically under `/media/<username>/<name>`. Clicking on the "Eject" button in the file manager unmounts it.

Once it's unmounted, it seems to be gone from the file manager. Is there a way to mount it again *without* un- and (re)plugging it?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/how-to-re-mount-a-usb-stick-after-unmounting-from-nautilus-without-disconnecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is NO you can't do it an easy way. nautilus file manager is built a way that you need to re-plug the device.

It is possible to patch Nautilus and change this behavior, but it is not worth the effort IMHO.

You can see more details at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/how-to-re-mount-a-usb-stick-after-unmounting-from-nautilus-without-disconnecting)

Comment: Well, not the answer I was hoping for, but the answer it is. Thanks!